# What is the Catholic view of what it meant for Jesus to be "called" Immanuel?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, life-of-jesus, gospel-of-matthew, names-of-god

Matthew 1:23 (NIV) says:

> “The virgin will conceive and give birth to a son, and **they will call him Immanuel** (which means “God with us”). *(Matthew 1:23, NIV)*

But, nowhere in the Gospels is Jesus addressed as Immanuel—directly or indirectly. It appears to me that that the word with its literal meaning implies more of an attribute than a name. So, what is the Catholic view on Jesus having been given the name Immanuel?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for asking an interesting, on-topic question. I do hope you'll get some good answers--and, of course, that you'll stick around here and browse some of the other questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Since this a purely exegetical question (i.e., it doesn’t really affect a fundamental teaching about Jesus), the Church does not have an “official” position on how to interpret Matthew 1:23.

In this passage, Matthew is simply applying the prophecy in Isaiah 7:14 to Jesus:

> Therefore the Lord himself will give you a sign. Behold, the virgin shall conceive and bear a son, and shall call his name Immanuel.

In context, Isaiah is prophesying the birth of Hezekiah, the son of Ahaz. (Hezekiah is portrayed in the Old Testament as a holy and prudent king, unlike his father.) However, Matthew sees that the prophesy has a deeper meaning in Jesus Christ, who is, after all “God-with-us” in a much more perfect way than Hezekiah ever was.

It seems that neither Jesus nor any of his disciples ever used *Immanuel* as an actual title. Hence Matthew is merely applying the prophecy to Jesus, since it describes Jesus’ condition (as God-made-man) very well.

(As a source for these reflections, I used the [*Ignatius Catholic Study Bible: New Testament*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1586172506), the notes for Matthew 1:23.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Catholic [Haydock Commentary](http://haydock1859.tripod.com/id1730.html), [Estius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willem_Hessels_van_Est) wrote:

> How happens it that nowhere in the gospels, or in any other part, do we find Christ called *Emmanuel*? I answer, that in the Greek expression the name is given for the thing signified; and the meaning is: He shall be a true Emmanuel, i.e., a God with us, true God and true man.